# Return XML Data From Asp.Net API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have an asp.net API that is using returning xml data from my Server.  This is the format the data is returned in (what I get when I type localhost.... into my address bar)

```
ID = 3, fname = a, lname = a, phone = 123, company = abcID = 4, fname = a, lname = b, phone = c, company = dID = 5, fname = aa, lname = bb, phone = cc, company = ddID = 6, fname = Frame, lname = Blame, phone = 5555555555, company = Company
```

When I attempt to use my C# to return the data from the API I get this error

> Error converting value "ID = 3, fname = a, lname = a, phone = 123, company = abc" to type 'TestData'

This is the method I am using to attempt to retrieve the data.  What must I do in order to have the data accurately returned?

```
        public List<TestData> GetGridInfo()
    {
        string URI = "http://localhost/api/getinfo";

        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(URI);

            var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestData>>(json);

            return message;
        }
    }
```

This is API syntax ->

```
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (XamarinEntities entities = new XamarinEntities())
        {
            result = entities.appinfoes.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.approveduser == null || x.approveduser=="No").Select(y =>  "ID = "+y.ID+", fname = "+ y.fname+", lname = "+ y.lname+", phone = "+ y.phone+", company = "+ y.company).ToList();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

EDIT -> The above syntax is how it looks on my local machine, if I use the server to hit localhost this is the format I get which looks like XML to me...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ArrayOfstring     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"     xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<string>ID = 3, fname = a, lname = a, phone = 123, company = abc</string>
<string>ID = 4, fname = a, lname = b, phone = c, company = d</string>
<string>ID = 5, fname = aa, lname = bb, phone = cc, company = dd</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

Comment: The data you shared is not a JSON data. If you have the code of API, can you need to share it here.

Comment: Your Title reads "Return **XML** Data From Asp.Net API" and you attempt to parse it as **Json** on the Client side and your given result of the API is neither XML nor JSON. I think you need to read into these Metalanguages before attempting to work with them.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - I posted the API method used to return the data in the API

Comment: You are returning a collection of strings. That is not JSON. You need to convert that to proper class object and then serialize it to JSON before returning from API. That's when you can deserialize the API response to some class at the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning JSON. you are returning an array of strings which is not JSON

you should do

```
public string Get()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (XamarinEntities entities = new XamarinEntities())
    {
        result = entities.appinfoes.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.approveduser == null || x.approveduser=="No").Select(y =>  "ID = "+y.ID+", fname = "+ y.fname+", lname = "+ y.lname+", phone = "+ y.phone+", company = "+ y.company).ToList();
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

above code will return JSON instead of string array

Change your code to receive List

E.g

```
public List<string> GetGridInfo()
{
    string URI = "http://localhost/api/getinfo";

    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(URI);

        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);

        return message;
    }
}
```

> A piece of advice use HttpClient instead of WebClient

Comment: This give me compile error of Can not implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Generic.IEnumerabl'<string>

Comment: see the updated answer, You have to change the return typew

Comment: I see what you did, you changed the method from IENumerbale<string> to get string...How should I update my "receiving" method `public List<TestData> GetGridInfo()` to account for this change?

Comment: Using your above method - When I try to retrieve the data with my GetGridInfo() method I get a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializiationException

Comment: Also Please Upvote the answer too, if it was useful.